# getHistorySize() always "0"

Tags: android, drag, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.3-gingerbread, motionevent

For ACTION_MOVE events, I'm obtaining the history size by calling `event.getHistorySize()` everything works perfectly on my Galaxy Nexus running Jellybean but on my LG Optimus 3D running Gingerbread, the history size is always "0". Does anyone know why this is? Did something change between 2.3 and 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since no one seems to have an answer to this, I'm just gonna explain the work around I had to do. On every `ACTION_MOVE` event, I simply stored the coordinates into an array myself, and then in upcoming `ACTION_MOVE` events instead of getting the coordinates from the event history, I just took them from the array. It's a straight forward work around, but the reasons as to why the issue was happening in the first place is still unclear.

Comment: I know this is an old one, but how did you store each coordinates in an array.. when I try it seeems like the array.add(x,y) is only storing the last coordinates :( and i'm trying to add them from `ACTION_MOVE`

Comment: I am facing the same problem as @yardie